# Speed up a function that checks for a sequence

Tags: performance, r

I created a  function `yes.seq` that takes two arguments, a pattern `pat` and data `dat`, the function looks for the presence of a pattern in the data and in the same sequence.

For example:

```
dat <- letters[1:10]
dat
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
pat <- c('a',"c","g")
 
 yes.seq(pat = pat,dat = dat)
[1] TRUE
```

because this sequence is in the pattern and in the same order.

`"a"` "b" `"c"` "d" "e" "f" `"g"` "h" "i" "j"

If, for example, we reverse the pattern, then we get FALSE:

```
yes.seq(pat = pat,dat =  **rev(dat)**   )
[1] FALSE
```

Here is my function:

```
yes.seq <- function(pat , dat){  
  lv <- rep(F,length(pat))
  k <- 1     
  for(i in 1:length(dat)){        
            if(dat[i] == pat[k]) 
              {
              lv[k] <- TRUE
              k <- k+1 
              }       
    if(k==length(pat)+1) break
  }
  return(  all(lv)   )
}
```

I am not satisfied with the speed of this function.  Can you help me with that?

Comment: can you add example data on which the function doesn't perform well?

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: [Match all elements of a pattern with a vector and in the same order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446800/match-all-elements-of-a-pattern-with-a-vector-and-in-the-same-order). Please read [Is it OK to cross post here and in SO?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10498/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-here-and-in-so) "No, it's not ok. Yes, it would be bad manners."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version:

```
yes.seq <- function(dat, pat) {
  paste(dat[dat %in% pat], collapse = "") == paste(pat, collapse = "")
}

yes.seq(dat, pat)
# [1] TRUE
yes.seq(dat, rev(pat))
# [1] FALSE
```